# How to display Google Artifact Registry repo's location using gcloud?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-artifact-registry

I try to display 3 fields about my repos using:

```
gcloud artifacts repositories list --format 'value(name,format,location)'
```

but this command doesn't show location, only name and format. How do I get location (eg: europe-west1) for my repos?

- I use gcloud 451.0.0
- I know I can run list command without any arguments and it displays many fields, including these 3, but can gcloud limit the fields to specific 3 (name/format/location) that I need?

Comment: try this `gcloud artifacts repositories list --format='value(name,format,location)'`

Comment: This command gives me [error](https://pastebin.com/Tic7qTXk) (I use gcloud 451.0.0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I encountered the same issue, but I tried uppercasing "location", and it worked:

`gcloud artifacts repositories list --format 'value(name,LOCATION)'`

Be careful: It's probably a bug on the gcloud cli, so this may break in the future

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the [Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/repositories/list-repos#view), to display the 3 fields i.e., name, format and location of a google artifact registry repository run the following command:

`gcloud artifacts repositories list --location=all`

**Update:**

I have tried with the same command you mentioned, and faced the same issue. Then I tried to display other fields like name, format and mode except location, it displayed output for the below command.

`gcloud artifacts repositories list --format 'value(name,format,mode)'`

The problem is with the location filed. It seems like it is not possible to view the location. It is worth raising a issue at [Public Issue Tracker](https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/getting-support#featurerequest).

In case  if you want to list images of artifact registry for a particular location, you need to be specifically mention location name along with the command as stated in this [Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/repositories/list-repos#view)

`gcloud artifacts repositories list --format 'value(name,format)' --location=us-central1`

Replace `us-central1` with the desired location.

Comment: It's not exactly what I want - it displays more fields, while I need only 3. Can gcloud do it? I know i can also run the command through eg. awk to extract only needed columns, but it would be strange if gcloud alone couldn't display only specific fields.

Comment: @Kossak Can you have a look at my updated answer.

Comment: ok, thank you, it seems like it's not possible in current version of gcloud

Comment: @Kossak see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)